# Get encryption type for wlan with tcpdump

Tags: libpcap, tcpdump, sniffing, wifi

How can I get the actual encryption type sent in Beacons from tcpdump? I have searched the manpage entry, Google, and website for tcpdump and pcap to no avail. I have the snaplen set to the highest value and the type = `IEEE802_11_RADIO` and can see a LOT of data from `tcpdump -i mon0 -vvv -le 'wlan type mgt subtype beacon'` and even without specifying the frame type as mgmt. I am using the latest stable version: 4.3.0 with libpcap 1.1.1

All the string says is "PRIVACY" if encryption is being used.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's related to programming...if it is, maybe you want to state so? Maybe there are alternate ways of obtaining the result you're looking for?

Comment: wow, i was trolled on my very first question here. The result will be used in a bash script that I use for statistical analysis. thanks for the down vote.

Comment: Using libpcap to just code something in C and do it myself, thanks anyways.

Comment: Downvotes and comments are not meant to hurt your feelings. Maybe I didn't understand your question correct. Maybe ***I*** needed an explanation.